# The Cartesian product of spaces is connected iff each component space is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

Good evening everybody, I'm doing exercise *II.4.2* in textbook Analysis I by Amann.

Could you please verify if my attempt contains logical mistakes/gaps! Thank you so much!

> [image]

**My attempt:**

**Lemma:** The Cartesian product of sets is open (closed) iff each component set is open (closed).

$\Longrightarrow$: Assume $X_j$ is not connected. WLOG, assume $X_1$ is not connected. Then there are two nonempty disjoint open subsets $X^1_1, X^2_1$ of $X_1$ such that $X^1_1 \cup X^2_1 = X_1$. Then $X^1_1 \times \prod_{j=2}^{n} X_j$ and $X^2_1 \times \prod_{j=2}^{n} X_j$ are nonempty, open, and disjoint by **Lemma**. Moreover, $(X^1_1 \times \prod_{j=2}^{n} X_j )\cup (X^2_1 \times \prod_{j=2}^{n} X_j) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} X_j$. Then $\prod_{j=1}^{n}$ is not connected.

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume $\prod_{j=1}^{n}$ is not connected. Then there are subsets $X^1_j, X^2_j$ of $X_j$ for all $1 \le j \le n$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^{n} X^1_j$ and $\prod_{j=1}^{n} X^2_j$ are nonempty, disjoint, and open such that $(\prod_{j=1}^{n} X^1_j) \cup (\prod_{j=1}^{n} X^2_j) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} X_j$. By our **Lemma**, $X^1_k, X^2_k$ are nonempty, disjoint, and open such that $X^1_k \cup X^2_k = X_k$ for at least some $1 \le k \le n$. As such, $X_k$ is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs are fine, but really, you don't need the lemma. You can argue directly: it suffices to prove the claim for two connected spaces $X$ and $Y$. The result then follows by induction.

So choose any $(x_0,y_0)\in X\times Y$ and set $T_x=(X\times y_0)\bigcup (x\times Y).$  Then, $T_x$ is a union of connected sets with a point in common and so is connected. And since each $T_x$ has $(x_0,y_0)$ in common, $X\times Y=\bigcup _{x\in X}T_x$ is connected.

Comment: I maybe wrong, but it seems to me that you proved only the $\Longleftarrow$ direction .

Comment: Yes, but the other direction is very easy: if $U,V$ disconnects $X\times Y$, then  to conclude write $U$ and $V$ as a union of basis elements $B_X$  and $B_Y$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and note the intersection must be empty which forces a separation on  at least one of the spaces $X, Y$.

Comment: Thank you so much ;)))

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You're not proving the $\Leftarrow$ implication well. If $\prod_i X_i$ is a union of two open sets these need **not** be of the form $\prod_i O_i$ at all.
Hint: actually use the hint you were given; it's the easiest way to go. See other answers too.

For the forward implication: just note that $X_j = \pi_j[\prod_i X_i]$ for any $j$ in the index set and continuous images of connected spaces are connected.